# stub a constant in a Grape api RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, stubbing, grape-api

Say I have a constant defined in a `Grape::API` class:

```
class Activities < Grape::API
  MAX_ALLOWED = 50000
  ...
end
```

And in the endpoint `desc`:

```
params do
  requires :data, type: Array, allow_blank: false, array_length: MAX_ALLOWED
end
```

I want to write a spec (using RSpec) to test the `array_length` option for the endpoint. I would like to stub the `MAX_ALLOWED` constant since I don't want to actually generate 50k of dummy data.

I tried `stub_const(API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED, 3)`

but got an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sub' for 40000:Fixnum`

I also tried `stub_const('API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED', 3)`

but that just didn't work.

Lastly, I tried:

```
before do
  allow_any_instance_of(API::V3::Resources::Activities).to receive(:MAX_ALLOWED).and_return(1)
end
```

and it also didn't work.

**EDIT:** also tried `allow` instead of `allow_any_instance_of` with same result.

**EDIT 2:** here's the failing spec:

```
context 'with more than 50,000 contacts' do
  let(:options) {{ 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }}

  # contacts_api, uri, resource, and request are defined elsewhere
  before { contacts_api :post, "#{uri}#{resource}", request.to_json, options }

  # Also tried this instead of stub_const:
  # before do
  #  allow_any_instance_of(API::V3::Resources::Activities).to receive(:MAX_ALLOWED).and_return(1)
  # end

  it 'returns a 400' do
    stub_const('API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED', 3)
    expect(response.status).to eq(400)
    expect(resp_body['error_key']).to eq('api error')
    expect(resp_body['error_message']).to eq('too many contacts')
  end
end
```

**EDIT 3:** with the request in the same `it` block as the `stub_const` (still fails):

```
it 'returns a 400' do
  stub_const('API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED', 3) # this doesn't work
  contacts_api :post, "#{uri}#{resource}", request.to_json, options
  expect(response.status).to eq(400)
  expect(resp_body['error_key']).to eq('contacts.api.bad_request')
  expect(resp_body['error_message']).to eq('too many contacts')
end
```

Any idea how to stub a constant defined in a `Grape::API` class for an RSpec test?

Comment: can you try `allow(API::V3::Resources::Activities).to receive(:MAX_ALLOWED).and_return(1)`.  Also you have 2 variable names , one in your example and one in your stubs... which is it?

Comment: @Anthony the `allow` didn't work unfortunately. And good catch (bad copy/paste), I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Stubbing needs to be done before your request. In this case, you can put it into a `before` block above the POST.

```
before { stub_const('API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED', 3) }
before { contacts_api :post, "#{uri}#{resource}", request.to_json, options }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I listed this as one of my failed attempts.

Comment: @mmichael: You are passing the result of `API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_CONTACTS_COUNT`, not the string `"API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_CONTACTS_COUNT"`

Comment: Please take another look at my question - I tried `stub_const('API::V3::Resources::Activities::MAX_ALLOWED', 3)` with the string.

Comment: @mmichael My apologies, didn't catch that. What was the error you got with the string? Also, can you post the spec itself?

Comment: No worries! There was no error with the string. The stub just didn't work and the spec failed - response was 200 when it should've been a 400. I just updated the question with the actual spec.

Comment: @mmichael: Corrected answer based on actual spec

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. No errors, but the test still fails. Seems like the stub is ignored. I also tried it with the `allow` instead of the `stub_const` but got the same result.

Comment: Try moving both request and `stub_const` into the `it` block, with `stub_const` as the first line?

Comment: Good suggestion, but alas, didn't work - see edit #3.

Comment: Please share the part of the code which checks the constant